# Character unhooks glasses from one ear and lets them dangle

Tags: identify-this-movie

I believe it's a recent movie, but the *only* thing I remember is that the main character would let his glasses dangle on his head from one ear. I remember he also grabbed them by the lens a couple times. These are things I've never seen someone who wears glasses (myself included) do, nor do I think any would.

I need the name of the movie for a different reason than watching it again. (I seem to remember thinking the movie wasn't very good, but had a well-known actor who seemed like they'd know better than to treat glasses so ineptly.) I remember Paul F. Tompkins talking about this on a podcast or in an interview, and *that's* what I'd like to revisit. Once I get the movie title I can continue.

This is such a little thing to go on, granted, but it struck me as **completely ridiculous**, and it struck PFT the same, so I'm guessing someone else here noticed and thought WTF? And they'll remember. Please don't immediately VTC as I'm confident that someone will get the movie even from just this character tick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe he was talking about Daniel Craig in *The Girl With The Dragon Tattoo*. [It's mentioned here](http://www.johnhodgman.com/post/15241851991/paulftompkins-yeah-im-gonna-start-wearing-my).

Comment: Thank you! I knew someone else would know immediately. SOOOOO silly and impractical. Now I just gotta track down the interview / podcast. Luckily, Paul F. Tompkins hasn't done many podcasts so it'll be a cinch...

Comment: Agreed. Probably a perceived trait of an 'absent-minded writer'.

Comment: I don't know if this is the one you're looking for, but he talks about it here (around 0:40): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwIR62t4B7Q

Comment: I wish I could give you ten more points and another "Accept." It was going to take a while to track down. YOU RULE! Today's winner of the Internet!

Comment: Glad to help. :) And thanks for the internet. My reign will be just and true. Puppy videos for all!!

Comment: Just noticed that Doc also did this briefly in [Inherent Vice](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1791528/). STOP DOING THIS PEOPLE! This should **not** become a *thing*.  :P